# Ubuntu 16.04 Bluetooth Can't find devices

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

Good day fellow Ubuntu people, I have a similar bluetooth problem not detecting any devices

I installed ubuntu version 16.04 on hp 4520s laptop and want to connect a bluetooth keyboard i have tried finding device normally like i have done on other ubuntu laptops and can't see the device at all, I then tested to see if the laptop detects any other devices like my phone and stil no devices are visible i also checked if i can connect keyboard to a windows laptop and i am capable of finding the device and connect to it.fault so far i have determined lies with the either faulty hardware or firmware on ubuntu laptop
i have also tried installing other bluetooth managers like blueman appplet in ubuntu and stil cannot find any devices.THis is how far i have come.I am new to ubuntu forums and any advise help would be appreciated

Here, below lists of system information.

`rfkill list`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hp-wwan: Wireless WAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 148f:1000 Ralink Technology, Corp. Motorola 
BC4 Bluetooth 3.0+HS Adapter
```

`dmesg | grep -i blue`:

```
[  177.053159] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  177.053185] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  177.053188] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  177.053190] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  177.053196] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  177.993897] Bluetooth: hci0 hardware error 0x37
[  189.515605] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  189.515607] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  189.515611] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  220.258415] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  220.258425] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  220.258433] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Added broader description of problem hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sudo bccmd psset -s 0x0000 0x028c 0x0001
```

And:

```
sudo service bluetooth restart
```

Answer (score 0):

After reboot bluetooth adapter was not detected by bluez. Tried to restart the service, did not work. Reloading module helped

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
sudo service bluetooth restart
```